# How to insert a picture in the attributes of the user jpegPhoto and thumbnailPhoto using PowerShell GUI?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

Using `PowerShell GUI` I make a simple form for changing a user's photo in `AD`.

Uploading photo to `picturebox`:

```cs
    $imgFile = (get-item 'd:\Foto\testUser.jpg')
    $picturebox.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($imgFile)
```

The `$picturebox.Image` is of type:

```cs
    > Write-Host $picturebox.Image.GetType()
    System.Drawing.Bitmap
```

Required attributes are of type:
`jpegPhoto` - `ArrayList`, `thumbnailPhoto` - `Byte[]`

How to convert `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `ArrayList` and `Byte[]` using `PowerShell GUI` to transfer image to attributes using `Set-ADUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the image data as (jpeg format) byte array from a picturebox:

```
$stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$picturebox.Image.Save($stream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg) | Out-Null
[byte[]]$pictureData = $stream.ToArray()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Using this byte array, you can use the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet to add the `thumbnailPhoto`:

```
try {
    # $User here is an AD User object you get using the Get-ADUSer cmdlet
    $User | Set-ADUser -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto = $pictureData } -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Note: for the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute, the image data has a **maximum size of 100KB (102400 bytes)**.
Usually you can't go wrong if you make sure the image is about 96x96 pixels.